# How to find the CDF and denisty?

Tags: probability-theory

Choose a number $U$ from the interval $[0, 1]$ with uniform distribution. Find the cumulative distribution and density for the random variables: (a) $Y = \left(U − \dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2$.

**My attempt:** I tried to think of a CDF that would be around $(0, 1)$. So, I thought a reasonable CDF would be $F(x) = 4x$, then, I tried to think of an interval for the CDF, which would be $\left(0, \frac{1}{4}\right)$ because I can get $[0, 1]$ again from the output of the CDF. However, the answer for the CDF was $F(x)= 2\sqrt{x}$. How do I find the correct CDF?

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative distribution function for $Y$, by definition, is the probability that $Y \leq y$. It is written given as a function in $y$.

Since we're given the probability distribution for $U$, rather than for $Y$, we should write the condition $Y \leq y$ in terms of the $U$ variable:
$$ {\rm cdf}(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P( \tfrac 1 2 - \sqrt y \leq U \leq \tfrac 1 2 + \sqrt y).$$

But since $U$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, we see that
$$ {\rm cdf}(y) =P( \tfrac 1 2 - \sqrt y \leq U \leq \tfrac 1 2 + \sqrt y) =  \begin{cases} 2 \sqrt y & y \in [0,\frac 1 4]  \\ 1 & y \in [\tfrac 1 4, \infty) \end{cases}$$

From here, we can also obtain the probability density function ${\rm pdf}(y)$ by differentiating ${\rm cdf}(y)$ with respect to $y$.

Comment: I was curious why there was 2 (y)^(1/2) but not (1/2) + y^(1/2) there? Or where did the 2*y^(1/2) come from?

Comment: It's just that $\int_{\frac 1 2 - \sqrt y}^{\frac 1 2 + \sqrt y} 1 \ du = 2 \sqrt y $. (The probability density function for the uniform distribution is $1$, and I'm integrating it over the interval $[\frac 1 2 - \sqrt y , , \frac 1 2 + \sqrt y]$.

Comment: O thank u Kenny!

Comment: Hey Kenny, woud I also use that integraton forumla if I am trying to find the cdf if we have Y=U^2?

Comment: If $Y = U^2$, then I believe ${\rm cdf}(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(- \sqrt{y} \leq U \leq \sqrt{y})$. So it should be very similar.

Comment: So therefore the cdf is 2*y^(1/2)?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: If Y=U^2 <(1/4), would I still use the integration formula to find the cdf,  Kenny?

Answer (score 0):

Use definition of CDF. Let $y \geq 0$.
\begin{align}
F_Y(y) &= P(Y \leq y) \\
&= P\left((U-\frac12)^2 \leq y\right) \\
&= P\left(-\sqrt{y} \leq U-\frac12 \leq \sqrt{y}\right) \\
&= P\left(\frac12-\sqrt{y} \leq U \leq \frac12+\sqrt{y}\right) \\
&= F_U\left(\frac12+\sqrt{y}\right)-F_U\left(\frac12-\sqrt{y}\right)  \\
\end{align}

Can you complete the rest?

what happens when $y<0$? what happens when $y$ is huge?

Comment: When y<0, the CDF(y)=-1, and when the Y>0, the CDF(y) goes to 1? Thank u for ur help!

Comment: Actually It is the opposite. $Y \geq 0$. Hence it is impossible for it to be less than a negative number. CDF is a non-decreasing function.

Comment: Also, Siong if I have something like Y=U-V, should I stll use the same theorem of P (Yis less than or equal to y)?

Comment: That is by definition of CDF. $F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y)$. Hence, it is natural to start from there. Unless of course, you know other stuff about $U$ and $V$ that you can take advantage of.